# Update $http call from api with radio buttons in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm pretty new at angular. As the title says, how do I update/or make a new call by filtering out "gender" here, so the API only returns females or males. The problem is that nothing really happens, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Please have a look at my code down below.

My code:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("randomUserController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.$watch("gender", function () {
        fetch();
    });

    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.gender = "male";

    function fetch() {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1&?gender=" + $scope.gender
        }).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.users.gender = response.data.results[0].gender;
                $scope.users.name =
                    response.data.results[0].name.first +
                    " " +
                    response.data.results[0].name.last;
                $scope.users.location =
                    response.data.results[0].location.city +
                    " " +
                    response.data.results[0].location.street +
                    " " +
                    response.data.results[0].location.state +
                    " " +
                    response.data.results[0].location.postcode;
                $scope.users.picture = response.data.results[0].picture.large;
            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response + " Some error occured");
            }
        );
        $scope.update = function (response) {
            $scope.gender = response.data.results[0].gender;
        };
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='randomUserController'>
  <div class='radio_group' data-label='Male'>
    <input id='male' name='gender' ng-click='update(response)'
           ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur'}"
           ng-model='gender' ng-required='!gender'
           type='radio' value='male'>
    <label for='male'></label>
  </div>
  <div class='radio_group' data-label='Female'>
    <input id='female' name='gender' ng-click='update(response)'
           ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur'}"
           ng-model='gender' ng-required='!gender' type='radio'
           value='female'>
    <label for='female'></label>
{{users.gender}}
</div>
```

The "update"-method or whatever it is called, I want that to trigger a new call to the API and return females or males. Is this even close to right? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why you say, "Nothing really happens". Plenty happens in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ex5XPLrQ3IeYhhSGOVM?p=preview).

Comment: @georgeawg I solved my own mystery... I took a closer look and I saw where the issue were and so on and fourth. Thanks anyway! :)